# spidev control using external hardware requirements

Tags: hardware

I have been playing with SPI inputs using RPI. This device give me `spidev0,0` and `spidev0,1`, if I do a `ls /dev` and I can connect electronics to the header pins via a 3008 slave ic.

I would like to also add a SPI device to my installation of Ubuntu 12.04LTS is this possible ?

What device would be required ? (I guess a USB to SPI)

Would this board then give me `spidev0,0` and `spidev0,1` (via `ls /dev`) the same as the RPI so I can control the SPI with Python (as I do now and the same way I do now just externally plugged into my PC)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get fairly expensive devices like [this](http://www.totalphase.com/products/aardvark-i2cspi/), and cheaper ones like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9235). The latter apparently has Linux drivers.

More advanced kits like [this](http://www.xdimax.com/sub20/sub20.html), which does I2C *(also on the Pi)* as well, and has other interesting things like Infrared stuff. It has Linux drivers on the page.

SPI-to-USB  chips such as [this](http://uk.farnell.com/microchip/mcp2210-i-so/ic-usb-to-spi-converter-20soic/dp/2078574) are available, but you would need to solder on the connectors etc.

You may find [this](http://openprog.altervista.org/OP_eng.html) and [this](http://www.devttys0.com/2011/11/speaking-spi-i2c-with-the-ft-2232/) interesting as well, and [this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/flashrom/) app may be of use.